# Run reports on all available parameter value

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I set several parameters for a report created in SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools). 
How can I run the report on all available parameter value and form a comprehensive 
report with each case per session?
Thanks a lot.

E.g. a report called 'data growth' with parameters @database and @tablename. A serial of available names for these two parameters. I would like to compile the report with all cases.

Comment: Perhaps you could show some sample data and what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: How you are running the reports? Scheduled with email subscriptions?

Comment: Depending on the specifics, you might be able to create a master report whose dataset has all possible parameter values.  Then include the current report as a subreport inside a tablix.

Comment: @Pinwar13: Yes. I ran the reports case by case via manual selection or input of the parameter value. I just would like to (1) make it automated across all parameter value and compile all case results in a single report for users; (2) make it running automatically every week and applied in mail subscription. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

**1.**
Manually include an additional `All` option into your parameter selections, either by adding a value in the menus or `union`ing the value if your parameter options are data driven, and set the source query to return all results when selected.

**2.**
Change your parameter to a `multi-value` parameter and change your source query to use `where database in(@database)` which will enable all combinations of your parameter to be selected, including all.

Comment: Thank you very much. Make sense and I will try the second way.